# used memory: c-array vs. NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I need to store up to 1.000.000 double values in different arrays (during calculation run). So far I'm using an `NSMutableArray` but it looks like the memory usage is huge. One idea is to use an c-array in order to avoid the storage of objects in the `NSMutableArray`. Is there a way to roughly estimate the memory usage of an NSMutableArray vs. and c-array? (I could not find any information about the size of an `NSNumber`-object vs. an primitive like double or float).

Thanks.

Comment: Why not run some benchmarks with instruments?

Comment: I find instruments not always helpful when it comes to memory usage. I hope to find some theoretical approaches. Is there a way in instruments to see the size of an specific object like the NSMutableArray object?

Comment: I wonder if a `sizeof(myArray)` tells you the real size?

Comment: Yes, I would guess that a NSArray of NSNumber will take on the order of 30-50 bytes per element.  An array of double will take 8.  Normally this is not worth worrying about, but with a million values it sort of starts to add up.  (You do, of course, have to do much more "manual" heap management with the "raw" arrays.)

Comment: @HotLicks, could you explain manual heap management? I do not understand.

Comment: @JFS It means that you shouldn't allocate space for 1 million doubles in one go (`malloc(1000 * 1000 * sizeof(double))`) but allocating the memory as you need it in smaller chunks, e.g 10 * 1000 doubles. Maybe also reusing old unneeded chunks for new data instead of releasing them.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I also mean that you must manage your `malloc` and `free` calls without the benefit of reference counts and ARC and autorelease pools, etc.  (Though there are a few tricks to get Objective-C memory management to help you.)

Comment: OK, do you have some good sources to read about using c-arrays in objc-code? It sounds like a tricky challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty clear that the memory consumption of `NSArray` will be bigger than of a raw C array.

How big the difference will be? Well, for every value in a `NSArray`, every primitive `double` has to be wrapped by a `NSNumber` so at least 20 B added for every value, probably a bit more.

One estimate can be found here: [Memory size of classes in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604120/memory-size-of-classes-in-objective-c)

Anyway, storing 1 000 000 values in memory is always a bit strange. Maybe it would be better to store them in a file and then load them when needed (e.g. using a memory mapped file).

Comment: the values get stored during an calculation run. It is an math-app. Is there no definition for memory usage of objects in objc?

Comment: Storing 1000000 values in memory is perfectly fine. And files are not a solution when one needs quick access.

Comment: @H2CO3 That depends on the use case. If random access is not required, files can be pretty fast, memory mapped files can be also fast enough.

Comment: @H2CO3 Accessing a memory mapped file containing doubles would be much faster than accessing a NSArray containing NSNumbers. And random access is fast, too - provided the system does not need to start "trashing". In fact, you have some sort of page cache with a LRU cache policy.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Who talks about an `NSArray`? (Well, the author of this answer... not me.) What I meant is of course `double arr[N]`.